# LatLngBounds.contains returns true even if LatLng is not within the defined boundary

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm stumped; does the ff. method intend to return `true` if a `LatLng` is within a `LatLngBounds` or does it only return `true` if the `LatLng` is part of the boundary set by `including`?

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)

So far my tests are counterproductive; it returns true even if the `LatLng` is outside the `LatLngBounds`.

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = // Get the boundaries of a location
LatLng target = cameraPosition.target; // returns the center of the camera
if (!latLngBounds.contains(target)) {
    // do processes
}
```

What I do is I display a `Toast` message if the camera is panned outside the `Polygon` (I also log it) but apparently, I have to scroll way away from the `Polygon` for it to show.

I use `Polygon.getPoints` as my `LatLngBounds`

[image: It should return false if it's outside the Polygon (LatLngBounds defined)]

Comment: Would highly appreciate it if the -1 was explained; the documentation is not clear (at least for me)

Comment: Are you strictly asking about the `contains()` method?

Comment: `contains()` will return true if you have explicitly added `LatLng` to bounds!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Well I navigate far away from the bounds, and it returns true. I am using the `CameraPosition.target` meaning center of the camera (like the one on the screenshot). So if it is explicitly added, it should only display if the center of the camera hits the bounds correct?

Comment: `cameraPosition.target` this will only return center of the map!

Comment: That it does @MuhammadBabar my point is; it returns `true` if I move away from the boundaries of my Polygon.

Comment: Won't a LatLngBounds be similar to a bounding box? In that case, it might be checking if a point is inside a box that fits around the polygon, which could explain why points outside your polygon are considered 'contained'

Comment: @fallaciousreasoning exactly. That clarified things for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a simple test, and the `contains()` method will return true for any point within the bounds, and will return false for what it considers points outside of the bounds.

I used an extreme example, with bounds set for the country of Australia, and tested with a point inside Australia, and a point in San Francisco.

The bounds:

```
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));
```

First test, with point within Australia:

```
           if (AUSTRALIA.contains(new LatLng(-31.693598,147.843026))){

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "inside bounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "outside bounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Result:

[image: InAustralia]

Then, tested with a point in San Francisco:

```
            if (AUSTRALIA.contains(new LatLng(37.7942635,-122.3955861))){
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "inside bounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "outside bounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Result:

[image: InSanFrancisco]

So, it looks like it's working as expected given a clear cut example.

The question is how far outside of the bounds you need to be in order for the `contains()` method to return false.

For this test I didn't make any calls to `including()`, so presumably the `contains()` method would return true based on the description in the documentation:

> Creates a new bounds based on a southwest and a northeast corner.
>
> The bounds conceptually includes all points where:
>
> the latitude is in the range [northeast.latitude, southwest.latitude];
>   the longitude is in the range [southwest.longtitude,
>   northeast.longitude] if southwest.longtitude ≤ northeast.longitude;
>   and the longitude is in the range [southwest.longitude, 180) ∪ [-180,
>   northeast.longitude] if southwest.longtitude > northeast.longitude.

If the bounds are modified by calls to `including()`, the documentation states that the bounds will be modified like so:

> Returns a new LatLngBounds that extends this LatLngBounds to include
>   the given LatLng. This will return the smallest LatLngBounds that
>   contains both this and the extra point.
>
> In particular, it will consider extending the bounds both in the
>   eastward and westward directions (one of which may cross the
>   antimeridian) and choose the smaller of the two. In the case that both
>   directions result in a LatLngBounds of the same size, this will extend
>   it in the eastward direction.

Comment: It should only be inside the bounds; and I've tried lat lngs outside the boundaries, but relatively close and it returns true.

Comment: @KevinD. Try a bit further out and see if it returns false, it should.  It might involve some complex math to figure out exactly where the bounds end!

Answer (score 0):

Are the values recieved for the boundary correct ? Maybe a permission error if not.

Comment: Pretty sure it's accurate (please see updated screenshot, the one highlighted in green is my `Polygon` in which it's Points are used by my `LatLngBounds`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I just came across an answer and wanted to highlight it here.  As of the current version of Google Maps, it appears that the LatLngBounds "contains" method internally does not check to see if an element is actually inside the bounds- it creates a square the size of the bounding box and checks if the point is inside it.  In your case, since your bounding box is diagonal, areas such as the Cebu Strait would return "true".

The way to determine if it is in the shaded area is more complex. Here's the formula I used, which seems to be working for me:

```
private fun List<LatLng>.polygonContains(point: LatLng): Boolean {
  var isInside = false
    for (i in this.indices) {
        val j = if (i == 0) size - 1 else i - 1
        val xLatitude = this[i].latitude
        val xLongitude = this[i].longitude
        val yLatitude = this[j].latitude
        val yLongitude = this[j].longitude
        val intersect = (xLatitude > point.latitude) != (yLatitude > point.latitude) &&
            point.longitude < (yLongitude - xLongitude) * (point.latitude - xLatitude) / (yLatitude - xLatitude) + xLongitude
        if (intersect) {
            isInside = !isInside
        }
    }
    return isInside
}
```